# Error using vl_gmm - Attempt to execute script as function

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, vlfeat

Hello I want to use Fisher Vector for my SIFT descriptors. I tried to use the function from VL_FEAT. I added the directory in MATLAB and also run vl_startup. It runs successfully but when I try the example

It gives me this error:

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT vl_gmm as a function:
C:\vlfeat-0.9.19.tar\vlfeat-0.9.19\vlfeat-0.9.19\toolbox\gmm\vl_gmm.m
```

Anyone help me how can i solve this?

Comment: This is sample code i used   
`numPoints = 1000 ;        
dimension = 2 ;    
data = rand(dimension,N) ;    
numClusters = 30 ;    
[means, covariances, priors] = vl_gmm(data, numClusters) ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions for you to get `VLFeat` working.  I'm not sure if you have tried them all, but I will suggest them as we go:

## Suggestion #1 - Compiling `VLFeat` if you downloaded just the source

Did you only download the source files?  If you did, did you compile `VLFeat` first?  Specifically, did you run `vl_compile` first when you downloaded the source?

Functions like `vl_gmm` require a MEX wrapper to be compiled before you can use the function.   If you look in the `toolbox/gmm` directory, there are two files: `vl_gmm.m` and `vl_gmm.c`.  `vl_gmm.m` is simply a MATLAB file that contains the documentation on how to use the function.  The actual function is in `vl_gmm.c` and it is a MEX file.  You only get this error if you didn't compile `VLFeat` first because it's trying to run the `.m` file by default, which contains nothing but documentation.

As such, make sure you compile `VLFeat` by running the `vl_compile.m` script before trying to run your example.

## Suggestion #2 - Download the pre-compiled binaries

Alternatively, you can get `VLFeat` pre-compiled by downloading the binaries: http://www.vlfeat.org/download/vlfeat-0.9.19-bin.tar.gz .  If you have trouble compiling the libraries, then download the actual pre-compiled binaries through the link I gave you, then try running `vl_setup.m` from there.